# Python - changing the variable inside for-loop gives different results

Tags: python, c++, r

When I try:

```py
v = [1, 1]
for i in range(len(v)):
    v.append(1)
    print(v)
```

The output is:

```py
[1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1]
```

But when I do:

```py
v = [1, 1]
for i in v:
    v.append(1)
    print(v)
```

It makes an infinite loop.

In both cases, the values of `range(len(v))` and `v` should be changed inside the for-loop. Can someone explain why there are different results with those two similar codes?

When I further try a similar code in R and C++:

For R:

```r
v <- c(1, 1)
for (i in v) v <- c(v, 1)
```

```r
v <- c(1,1)
for (i in seq_along(v)) v<-c(v, 1)
```

For C++:

```cpp
vector<int> v{1, 1};
for (auto i : v) v.push_back(1);
```

The resulting `v` is `[1, 1, 1, 1]`, indicating that they have a similar behavior to Python's `for i in range(len(v)):`.

But in C++ (and Java):

```cpp
vector<int> v{1, 1};
for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) v.push_back(1);
```

produces an infinite loop, indicating that it has a similar behavior to Python's `for i in v:`. What is happening?

Comment: In the first case, you're iterating only twice, an initially prefixed `len(n)` size. In the second, as many as elements are in the iterable. And since you're adding a value on each iteration, it is an infinite iterator

Comment: `range(len(n))` is a range object that has been initialized with the value of `len(n)`. Why should the range object change during iteration?

Comment: What about the R language? `for (i in v)` gives a different result than that in Python.

Comment: Your first C++ attempt has undefined behaviour, so anything might happen.

Comment: Each language has different rules, different syntax, etc.  The C++ code will cause an obvious infinite loop -- you are resizing the vector each time `push_back()` is called, thus `size()` will keep increasing., so `i` will never catch up to `size()`.  You don't need Java or python, or R to see this.

Comment: Are there references to the exact behaviors of for-loop for different languages?

Answer (score 0):

doing

```
for i in var:
```

means that the loop will run for each item in var then in the loop you append items to var creating an infinite loop

```
range(len(var))
```

however repeats the loop for the number of elements in var when the lopp is started so when the loop is appended to the loop run doesn't extend

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
v = [1, 1]
for i in range(len(v)):
    v.append(1)
    print(v)
```

You iterate a list that contains `[0 1]`. That list is contructed by using the length of `v` but is otherwise unrelated to `v`.

Here

```
v = [1, 1]
for i in v:
    v.append(1)
    print(v)
```

You iterate elements of `v`. As you append elements to `v` inside the loop you never reach the end.

Concerning C++ and R: they are different languages, so it should not be a big surprise that code that looks similar syntax-wise does something different.

Answer (score 0):

```
v = [1, 1]
for i in v:
    v.append(1)
    print(v)
```

When you do the above code - it means , you are looping through an `array/list - v` - & inside the loop going on adding elements to it - it will never end.

When you do the code with `len(v)` - `len(v)` will be evaluated and assigned as fixed number of times to iterate.

However, ideally one shouldn't be messing up with the variable used for defining number of iterations of loop inside the same loop.

Answer (score 0):

This happened because in every iteration of your for loop, you're updating your vector v. Then when it's run again It will read a vector bigger then the last iteration which will results in and endless loop, for instance:

```
 v = [1, 1]
 for i in v:
    v.append(1)
    print(v) ## By this point you have v = [1,1,1], then let`s start the loop again
 # v = [1, 1, 1]
 for i in v: # v now has the len(v) = 3, not 2. And it keeps getting bigger and bigger, resulting in an infinite loop.
    v.append(1)
    print(v) # now v = [1,1,1,1]
```

The best approach is to set a limit to your iteration using `range`.